# Not understanding this integral of unit step

Tags: dirac-delta, singularity

[image]

Singular functions are extensively used in signals for EE, I'm trying to not get lost in the initial parts of the book I'm following. However, I cant understand how/why the author uses $\mu$ as a function of $\tau$ initially. This often appears in singular functions defined through integrals. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your confusion correctly, $\tau$ is what's called a "dummy variable" in this integration.  You're probably expecting something a bit more like
$$
f(t) = \int_{t_0}^{\color{red} t} u({\color{blue} t} - t_0) \, d{\color{blue} t}.
$$
However, this notation is problematic, since the symbol $t$ is playing two roles in this expression:  one as the variable we're integrating over ("inside" the integral, colored blue) and one as the limit of the integration (colored in red.)  This can lead to confusion;  for example, if I want to take the derivative of $f(t)$
$$
\frac{df}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt} \left[ \int_{t_0}^{\color{red} t} u({\color{blue} t} - t_0) \, d{\color{blue} t} \right],
$$
how does this derivative with respect to $t$ act on the "blue" $t$'s in the expression in brackets?

The answer is that it doesn't, since the variable of integration is a "dummy" — it doesn't appear in $f(t)$ once you've evaluated the integral.  So to remind ourselves that these $t$'s are playing different roles, we use a different symbol for the "dummy" variable:
$$
f(t) = \int_{t_0}^{t} u(\tau - t_0) \, d\tau.
$$
If we then try to take the derivative of this function, we have
$$
\frac{df}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt} \left[ \int_{t_0}^{t} u(\tau - t_0) \, d\tau \right]
$$
which is equal to $u(t - t_0)$ by the [first fundamental theorem of calculus.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part)

Answer (score 0):

Unit step function is defined as:
$$
u(t) = \cases{1 & if $t\ge0$ \\ 0 & if $t<0$}
$$

Using this definition helps when solving integrals because allows to split domain of integration in a simple way and your example is one of those; $u(\tau - t_0)$ means that the value is $0$ when $\tau < t_0$ and $1$ when $\tau \ge t_0$  so when you solve the integral you write this:
$$
\int_0^t u(\tau - t_0) d\tau = \int_0^{t_0} u(\tau-t_0) d\tau + \int_{t_0}^t  u(\tau-t_0) d\tau = \int_0^{t_0} 0 \cdot d\tau + \int_{t_0}^t  1 \cdot d\tau 
$$
Even changing the variable of integration $\tau \rightarrow T = \tau - t_0$ lead to:
$$
\int_0^t u(\tau - t_0) d\tau = 
\int_0^{t_0} u(\tau-t_0) d\tau + \int_{t_0}^t  u(\tau-t_0) d\tau = 
\int_{-t_0}^{0} u(T) \cdot dT + \int_{0}^{t-t0}  u(T) \cdot dT
$$

Comment: It doesn't matter the variable of integration because what only matters is the limits of integration because the value is always 1 or 0, is that it?

Comment: Well, the variable of integration and integration limits are linked, so the variable of integration matters. The purpose here is to separate 'not a nice function' in parts as sum of 'nice functions' and calculate them.